# How to code for a bigger cold start in FaaS

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to measure the response time as the number of instances increases to find ways to optimize provisioning.

I prepared an activity function that creates 5MB of data, as shown in the code below, but the results show no noticeable cold start.

Could you give me an example of a code that would have a larger cold start time?
If possible, it would be nice if it is one that does not connect to any service other than the Azure Blob Service.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# Client functions are mostly irrelevant, so some are omitted.
app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
    return f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput:\n {output_str}" 


@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    activity_func = context.call_activity(f"activity{i}", size)
    return time.perf_counter() - start


@app.activity_trigger(input_name="size")
def activity1(size: int) -> int:
    data = np.random.rand(size) 
    df  =  pd.DataFrame(data) 
    df_ = df.to_dict()
    return len(df_)
```

Answer (score 0):

To induce a noticeable cold start time in an Azure Functions app without connecting to external services, you can increase the complexity of your function, for instance by introducing a time-consuming computation. Here's an example in Python using the Azure Functions Python

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where is the example of the Python code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).